# Error - "should be zero or 1 controller arg"

Tags: python, game-engine, error

I'm trying to use some python filters in the UPBGE and keep getting this error. There is one large file called `filters.py` with numerous filter scripts that I am using and whenever I try to use one of the filters using the python module controller (`filters.filter`) I get this error: `filters.filter takes (X) args`, should be zero or 1 controller arg" where X is the number of arguments next to where the filter is on the list in the script (i.e. `def filter(value1=1, value2=2, etc)`. How do I get blender be able to recognize more than "zero or 1 args" and get my script working?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least one controller logic-block setup with Python script? That controller needs to be on a sensor (usually an Always sensor). if that's not the problem, take another look at the API for the functions or objects associated in the script (maybe provide a link?)

I've had trouble running UPBGE, so I've no experience with it.